# How do I redirect console output of command to a logfile?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface, postgresql

My OS is RHEL5.

I want to direct the console output produced by the following database command to a log/file.

```
psql mydb mydbuser -c "VACUUM ANALYZE VERBOSE"
```

I've tried out the following commands and is not working as expected.  But it is printing output to the terminal console instead.

```
psql mydb mydbuser -c "VACUUM ANALYZE VERBOSE" > vacuum.log
psql mydb mydbuser -c "VACUUM ANALYZE VERBOSE" | tee vacuum.log
```

Here, in this case, is not the output produced by this command a standard input/output/error?

NOTE: [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html) is a terminal-based front-end to PostgreSQL. It enables you to type in queries interactively, issue them to PostgreSQL, and see the query results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redirect stderr as well.

```
psql mydb mydbuser -c "VACUUM ANALYZE VERBOSE" &> vacuum.log
```

Comment: @Ignacio: Thanks, that's working perfectly as expected. Actually, I'm not a Linux expert, for me to understand this better, `&` is the stderr and `>` is standard output?

Comment: `>` is stdout, `2>` is stderr, `&>` is both.

Comment: @Ignacio: Thanks again. Can you share with me some useful resource about Linux redirection operators?

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

Comment: @Gnanam: Also, the Bash Manual section on [Redirections](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC39) and Greg Wooledge's BashGuide section on [Redirection](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#Redirection).

Comment: @Dennis: Thanks for sharing that additional useful links.